# Uk visitors visa after previously having ILR visa?

Tags: uk-visitor-visa

I am Ukrainian, my son and husband of 10 years are both British. In 2007 I came to the UK on spouse visa, I was granted ILR in 2009 but in 2010 we have moved to Thailand with my husband to work and travel. Our son was born here in 2014.

My husband has been traveling between London and Thailand for a year, setting up a base for us to return home. He is self employed as he has been all his life. Now he has regular jobs its difficult to travel

We are planning to move permanently to the UK but not yet.

How likely am i to get visitors visa approved? A lawyer I consulted was not very optimistic and quoted £1200 to do the application for us.

Thank you guys !